# Is there a way to copy multiple values from excel and paste them into access order form?

Tags: excel, database, forms, ms-access

Some managers would like the ability to either copy and paste, or upload 100+ part numbers at the same time along with the quantity desired onto an access order form. How I have it set up now, is: They click 'Add new product button' and a subform appears and they either use the combo down box or type in their material number and then type in their quantity. One by one. Click save, and then restart that process. When attempting to roll this out, I received a lot of backlash on it not being capable to copy and paste many lines into the order form  as some of the managers have hundreds of parts to add... Is this even possible to do?? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4v3z.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/598Hx.png)

Comment: Rather than looking to copy and paste the data into a form, you should look at importing the data into the access table behind the the form  [This SO search should help](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-access%5D+import+data)

Comment: It is possible to copy/paste entire record row(s) to form in Datasheet View.